# How do I set my RAILS_ENV with Passenger and Apache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I've been everywhere today looking for the way to properly set my RAILS_ENV for Passenger. I want to use the test environment now that the site is on my server, but I don't want it to be production because I'm having database issues.

I've been directed to [this part of the documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerAppEnv), but it didn't make any sense to me. I had `PassengerAppEnv RAILS_ENV = 'test'` in my Apache .conf file for the site and -- as expected -- that didn't' work.

I've also set `RAILS_ENV = 'test'` in `config/environment.rb` of my Rails site, but that didn't work either.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use Capistrano or something else to deploy your app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're close, but not quite correct. Here is how you set it:

```
<Directory /path/to/app/public>
Allow from all
Options -Multiviews
# ^ for Apache 2.4+
Require all granted
RailsEnv development # < place desired environment here 
</Directory>
```

Basically Passenger will see the line in the configuration file and then set it for you. It uses the more Apache style syntax of:

```
 Name [space] <value>
```

So you don't need all the quotes or any Ruby style syntax at all.